# intellij can't resolve grails.plugin

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, spring-security

I am using Grails 2.3.3 and IntelliJ ultimate 12.1.6 on my Vista 32 machine.

I used grails command line to create a new app and then added spring security and spring security ui. My BuildConfig.groovy plugins section contains

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"
compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC1"
```

I ran

```
grails s2-quickstart
grails s2ui-override auth
grails s2ui-override register
```

My generated RegisterController looks like this:

```
class RegisterController extends grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController {
}
```

the grails.plugin is red and unresolved and no matter what I try I can't get IntelliJ to resolve grails.plugin

Grails compiles and runs the app without issue, and if I override methods I find in the source code for the spring ui RegisterController they are correctly wired in to the app, but I can't even compile from intell and I can't get intellij to help me override code.

I thought maybe creating the project outside of IntelliJ was an issue so I created a new Grails project using the IntelliJ interface, the plugins still do not resolve.

I tried adding the plugins as runtime with no success.

I have spent the afternoon and evening researching this with no success. There are questions similar to this with major versions 10 and 11 of IntelliJ but nothing current, so I am resolved to asking for help to get IntelliJ to recognize the Grails plugin classes. I can post an entire small sample project if necessary.

Thanks.
Dave

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I often have this issue when I place a new plugin into my BuildConfig.groovy, but not typically when I add a jar dependency.

I resolve it by doing the following in the menu: **Tools > Grails > Synchronize Grails Settings**

You can tell whether or not a plugin is synchronized in IDEA by navigating in the Project view to grails-app > target > work > plugins. Each synchronized plugin with have a tiny blue square over the bottom right corner of the directory icon. If it doesn't have that icon, it isn't synchronized with IDEA properly.

Comment: Additionally, a regular Gradle project has this same issue. You can open the Gradle panel on the right side of the menu. It too has a synchronize button that looks the same (like a refresh symbol).

Comment: th3morg's comment is spot on for grails 3 (which is gradle driven). Hitting the doohickey in the gradle pane of the IDE was the only way to get it to find my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Using IntelliJ 13.1.5 and Grails 2.4.3 with Maven there is an issue with 2 different groovy-all jars being pulled in by the IDE. 
The way to resolve it is to go to Module Settings and under both the project and projectGrialsPlugins modules modify the User Grails library entry. Click the edit button(pencil) and remove the groovy-all.2.3.3.jar from the project.

Remember if you close the project and reopen it those settings may need to be reapplied.